# Cannot Understand code

Tags: python

I am learning python.I came across this small code snippet

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for a[-1] in a:
    print(a[-1],end="")
```

I expected the output to be `3333` because every the loop iterates `a[-1]` will be 3 only. But actual output is `0122`.Finally when loop is terminated,when I checked the value of `a` it is also modified as `[0,1,,2,2]`.How did the `list` change? Can someone explain me how this code works?

Comment: Because `for x in iter` **assigns to `x`**. So implicitly you write `a[-1] = a[0]`, `a[-1] = a[1]`, and so on. When we finally reach `a[-1] = a[-1]` it will take the last assigned element, which is `a[-2]`.